# Manage scarce resources - prioritize routing over nextcloud using nice

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, nextcloud

I set up my RaspberryPi Model 4 B with Raspbian 10.4 as a [wifi router](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md). I also installed NextCloud. In some situations (uploading many files at once), Nextcloud can overload the system (read: CPU, memory hasn't been a problem so far) and the internet connection for the clients connected to the routher becomes veeeery slow.

@goldilocks suggested using `nice` to set the priority of the relevant processes.

- Is it better to lower the niceness of the processes needed for routing, to increase the niceness of `apache2` and `mysql`, or both?
- Which processes are responsible for the router functionality?
- How do I set the niceness of processes which are started at startup or by other processes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix) -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for the tip! I edited the question to reflect my open questions after doing some research on `nice` (I am an networking and server noob).

Comment: Please let me know if you think this question suits a different stackexchange better. I chose this one since the resource scarcity and combination of router and webserver might be less common outside the pi world.

Comment: You can add nice to Apache (not mysql). But if I understand correctly, you are uploading a large file, right? You want to prioritize the network: priority on routing and not on receiving files, right?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi well, I generally want to prevent high load from the nextcloud affecting the routing. The worst load I had so far was not when uploading a single large file, but lots of photos at the same time, but there might be other situations as well (downloading a folder which needs to be zipped e.g., or running other nextcloud applications maybe). But yes, I want to prioritize the network.

Comment: Network should not use much CPU, and it has already high priority. You may have a problem with disk (which my stop networking I/O) or you may want to prioritize "routing" instead of "incoming" traffic. Probably it requires a lot of experimenting (optimization is never "following recipes").

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi okay, thanks. I connected locally for the upload, so this traffic was also coming via wifi, and I saw a really high CPU load with a lot of free RAM left, so that's why I was guessing CPU was the bottleneck. How does disk access affect networking I/O?

Comment: `vmstat 5 5` can help to find some i/o problems. I/O are limited, e.g. because of the bus usage, but also CPU: RP must handle both (if it is not using DMA or network card offloading, I'm not sure how much DMA could use RP). IO from network or from disk, for point of view of a CPU are identical: they uses same resources.

Comment: You should have a look w/ `htop` or some similar tool to determine which processes are using the most CPU when the system is clogged.  WRT routing, the kernel does most of the work, but it is usually in service to some process -- try lowering the niceness of `hostapd` all the way.